# User Interface Layout in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Kinda new in Microsoft visual C#. I have made a simple program[image]. Everything is working perfectly fine, unfortunately the tricky part for me is i do not know how to layout my objects properly. I would like to copy the layout of the Microsoft visual C# interface[image], wherein the panels adjust to their predefined ratio and proportion whenever the main form is re-sized and the user may adjust the width and height of each panel. Any readings or code would be a lot of Help. THANKS A LOT!

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF?

Comment: The anchor property of the controls is not what you are looking for?

Comment: @lan: In the property window you can find `System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox`, so WinForms?!

Comment: @sll: True... but maybe just stumbled across Winforms and doesn't know about WPF.

Comment: DockPanel Suite is popular, take the first google hit.  The screenshot is scary, there's little sign of any code.  Pretty classic trap.  Make your program useful first.  The UI doodahs can wait until version 2.

Comment: @HansPassant: If it's homework, he might not have a choice

Answer (score 0):

You could do a number of things:

- Allow automatic layout using something like a [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx)
- Allow resizing of controls using a [Splitter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitter%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
- Look at custom implementations to provide more advanced functionality [Collapsible Splitter](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3025/Collapsible-Splitter-control-in-C)

Comment: @user1176111: If you find answers useful click the up-arrow to upvote them, and remember to mark an answer as the one you wish to accept if one fits the bill.

Answer (score 0):

> Well follow these tutorial links to know about resizing in windows
>   using Dock and Anchor property. Along this the layout control will
>   help you to manage the layout - [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx) and
>   TableLayoutPanel, Panel, GroupBox etc.

---

[Designing Resizable Windows Forms in Visual Studio .NET](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/6964)
[Manage WinForm controls using the Anchor and Dock properties](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/manage-winform-controls-using-the-anchor-and-dock-properties/6165908)

This [one](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/6964/1954) is much better to understand.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple start the anchor property is what you want. so for instance if you set all four anchors for that left hand control, and the parent window changes size it will will resize proportionally.

After that it starts getting complicated. Adding panels and then putting your controls inside them. Setting Dock to left, or top or fill. Grow and shink on scrollable controls. Splitter bars.

And last ditch handling resize events and calculating positions and sizes.

Sit down and have a think about what you want to happen, play around with minimum and maximum height and widths, ie no point in working out waht your form is going to look like when it's postage stamp sized...

PS Don't forget VS allows floating panels, and persists (well some times sort of) user choices in the layout, that's a bigger job.

Answer (score 0):

Place a TableLayoutPanel as the base control, anchor it to all sides, define as many columns and rows as you like with "percentage" sizes.

Then place different sections of your form in different table cells. Properly dock your controls in each cell.

Can also use a split container above table if needed.

The ideal order should be like below

SplitContainer
    TableLayoutPanel
        Panel
            Controls